# Lookup field goes on child or parent object?

Tags: relationships

Can someone give me a way to remember which object the lookup field and master-details fields go when creating a relationship?

If I want to see custom object "c" in the contact object's related list, where do I put a md or custom fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The related list is always on the *parent* object, and the lookup or master-detail field is always on the *child* object. "The child looks up to the parent" might be a useful mnemonic here. In order to see a list of custom objects on the contact object, the custom object would have the lookup or master-detail field. The main difference between lookup fields and master-detail fields is this: a lookup field does not need to be populated (a child can survive without its parent), but a master-detail relationship does need to be populated (the details cannot exist without their master).

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the field, it is literally described to you (at least for the master-detail):

> Creates a special type of parent-child relationship between this
>   object (the child, or "detail") and another object (the parent, or
>   "master")

A lookup field, as described in the doc is very similar to a master-detail (same relationship actually) however, it comes with some limitations.

All these are clearly described in the documentation at [Object Relationships Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&type=5).